# Custom Icon for Gnome Shell Extension in Top Panel not visible

Tags: gio, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I try to use a custom SVG for my GNOME shell extension as status icon in top panel. But the custom icon is never shown, just the widget's label text. And I find no error in log output.

When I try to set a build-in icon like "*system-search-symbolic*" it works, this icon is shown.

This is my code snippet (the SVG is in an "icons" directory of my extension: `/home/myusername/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/my-widget@my-widgets/icons/timeclock-16x16.svg`):

```js
// ...

let widgetBoxLayout = new St.BoxLayout();

let iconPath = `${Me.path}/icons/timeclock-16x16.svg`;
// just for debug if path is correct
log(`${Me.metadata.name}: Icon path=${iconPath}`);
let gicon = Gio.icon_new_for_string(`${iconPath}`);
let icon = new St.Icon({ gicon: gicon, style_class: 'system-status-icon', icon_size: 16 });

// this works for build-in icon:
//let icon = new St.Icon({ icon_name: 'system-search-symbolic', style_class: 'system-status-icon'});

widgetBoxLayout.add(icon);
widgetBoxLayout.add(this.widgetText);

//...
```

Maybe it's a problem that there is an "@" char in icon path?
But why no error is logged?

What is the correct code to use a custom icon for status panel?

(I have GNOME Shell 3.30.2)

Answer (score 4):

Oh no! This one of these "fight for weeks alone, finally ask the crowd, suddenly know the solution yourself" cases ...

The icon *was* actually visible but since I use a *dark theme* and the icon itself is also *dark* it was not "visible". I inverted the colors of this icon and now I can see the icon next to my text in top panel.

Now I have to find out which icon to use depending on user's theme, but the original issue is solved.

Maybe this answer helps other developer making same stupid error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `-symbolic` icons to allow automatic theme aware re-colorization of the icons. Just change the file name of the icon to `timeclock-symbolic.svg`, at least this should be your first step if every other aspect is fine.